# Doubts on Semiconductor Physics

Tags: physics, bipolar

I'm really confused about the working of a Bipolar Junction Transistor (N-P-N).
Just consider the below figure:

1) Clearly the Base-Emitter junction is forward biased and Base-Collector junction is reverse biased, so when the current Ib flows to the base
it meets the current Ic, but they are in opposite directions, so won't they cancel each other? If that happens, then, when we increase Ib, Ic should decrease.But in reality the opposite is observed, i.e whenever Ib is increased Ic also increases proportionately.Why does that happen?

[image]

2) I also have a doubt about the current flow, will the current Ib flow as depicted in the below given diagram?

[image]

Comment: $I_B$ is the current flowing in to the base. The current flowing out of the emitter is $-I_E$. You shouldn't be labelling the current out of the emitter as the base current. Have you learned Kirchoff's Current Law yet?

Comment: Google "Chenming Hu". He helped invent the FinFET. He works at UC Berkeley. On his website, his semiconductor physics book is available to download for free. It's one of the best-written textbooks I've ever read.

Comment: Here is download link   https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Book-Chapters-and-Lecture-Slides-download.html

Answer (score 1):

(1) It is simply Kirchhoff's law $$I_E=I_B+I_C$$

(2) $I_C$ is (approximately) proportional to $I_B$ because both currents are determined by the base-emitter forward bias voltade $V_{BE}$ via the exponential proportionality factor (diode factor) $\exp (qV_{BE}/kT)$ $$I_C \propto I_B \propto \exp (qV_{BE}/kT)$$ The proportionality factor between collector and base current is called the dc current amplification factor. ($q$ is the electron charge, $k$ the Boltzmann constant, $T$ the absolute temperature)

Comment: Thank you for clearly stating that "both currents are determined by the base-emitter forward bias voltage" - as you know, there are some people (and even some textbooks), which are wrong in saying that Ic would be controlled by IB.

Answer (score 0):

"when the current Ib flows to the base it meets the current Ic, but they are in opposite directions, so won't they cancel each other" - there are three currents at the boundary of the device:  *Ib*, *Ic*, *Ie*.  By convention we say that current *into* the device is positive.

Then conservation of charge (the "cancel" you're thinking about) then means that *Ib+Ic+Ie* is zero:  No current accumulates in the device.

*Ib* and *Ic* can change independently because *Ie* changes.

Comment: @Bob Jacobson - There are also different conventions  considering the current directions in npn and pnp-bipolar transistors. As shown in the graph for the npn transistor, $I_C$ and $I_B$ positive when flowing in, $I_E$ positive when flowing out. The opposite positive current directions in pnp-transistors.